# How to retrieve data from a Java Map correctly?

Tags: java, oop, hashmap

I want to fill place holders of the following text with a Java Map.

```
String text = "Media file %s of size %s has been uploaded";
```

This is how I entered values into the map.

```
Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();

properties.put(MediaFile.fileName, "Sample 001");
properties.put(MediaFile.fileSize, "2Mb");
```

I expect output text to be like this.

```
Media file Sample 001 of size 2Mb has been uploaded
```

But I get this as the output.

```
Media file 2Mb of size 2Mb has been uploaded
```

I have created a class as following to keep variable fileName and fileSize.

```
public class MediaFile {

    public static String fileName;
    public static String fileSize;

}
```

However if I use it like below it works fine. But I want to separate fileName and fileSize. But I'm not sure whether I have implemented the MediaFile class correctly. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
properties.put("fileName", "Sample 001");
properties.put("fileSize", "2Mb");
```

Comment: Why are `fileName` and `fileSize` static? Don't mark things as `static` unless you know exactly why. Not to mention the fact that you never initialize them.

Comment: if MediaFile.fileSize is not static then it will return null values in hashmap . because of this old dublicate value is getting replace with new null

Comment: @Tejal It is returning null values *anyway*, as he has never initialized these values. Why exactly would every `MediaFile` have the same name and size? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: What [tag:arrays] has to do with it is another mystery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `MediaFile.fileName` and `MediaFile.fileSize` as keys, both contain the same value - `null` - since you never initialize them. Therefore the second `properties.put()` replaces the value of the first `properties.put()` (since `HashMap`s don't allow duplicate keys).

You might want to use constants:

```
public class MediaFile {
    public static final String fileName = "fileName";
    public static final String fileSize = "fileSize";
}
```

Now your constants are initialized with different values, and your original code will work.